# Python struct module reading multiple floating points from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418878/read-specific-sections-of-a-binary-file-containing-32-bit-floats/53419470?noredirect=1#comment93749036_53419470), which solved the beginning of my issue, I am still faced with the problem of not being able to read multiple 32-bit floating point values at a time with the `struct` module.

```
import struct


class Float32(object):
    """32-bit floating point object."""

    # 4 bytes in each 32-bit floating point (8 bits in a byte)
    size = 4


class DATA(object):
    """Object representation of information from a DATA file."""

    def __init__(self, DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes):
        self.DATA_filepath = DATA_filepath
        self.raw_data = self.read_DATA(DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes)

    def read_DATA(self, DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes):
        """Open DATA (*.data) file and read its contents."""

        # initialize an empty list for the raw data
        raw_data = []

        # read binary data into the list
        with open(DATA_filepath, 'rb') as input_DATA:
            for idx, offset in enumerate(offset_values):
                input_DATA.seek(offset)
                buffer = input_DATA.read(Float32.size) * data_sizes[idx]
                format_string = str(data_sizes[idx]) + 'f'
                value = struct.unpack(format_string, buffer)
                raw_data.append(value)

        return raw_data
```

The variable `format_string` looks like `64f` or whichever number that `data_sizes[idx]` is in each loop iteration concatenated with `f` (see the [`struct` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) and the linked question above for the rationale here). However, this method seems only to read the same floating point number into every array index the same number of times aas `data_sizes[idx]`, rather than unique values. I know that my file should not produce this result, as I am translating this to Python from a working MATLAB script.

What am I doing wrong with my implementation?

**EDIT:**

Thanks in part to the answer, I noticed some errors in my source code (both the one pointed out by the user and others that compromised how I was trying to read from the file). I'm adding the edited source code to flesh out the issue and give more explanation for the credit given to the accepted answer.

```
class DATA(object):
    """Object representation of information from a DATA file."""

    def __init__(self, DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes):
        self.DATA_filepath = DATA_filepath
        self.raw_data = self.read_DATA(DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes)

    def read_DATA(self, DATA_filepath, offset_values, data_sizes):
        """Open DATA (*.data) file and read its contents."""

        # initialize an empty list for the raw data
        raw_data = []

        # read binary data into the list
        with open(DATA_filepath, 'rb') as input_DATA:
            for idx, offset in enumerate(offset_values):
            input_DATA.seek(offset)
            buffer = input_DATA.read(data_sizes[idx])
            format_string = str(int(data_sizes[idx] / Float32.size)) + 'f'
            value = struct.unpack(format_string, buffer)
            raw_data.append(value)

        return raw_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing:

```
buffer = input_DATA.read(Float32.size) * data_sizes[idx]
```

you're just reading **ONE** float and replicating it data_sizes[idx] times.

What you simply want to do is the following:

```
buffer = input_DATA.read(Float32.size * data_sizes[idx])
```